# How to mock a dependency before SpringBoot starts up

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, spring-mockk

I'm trying to write an integration test for a controller in SpringBoot app, as follows:

```
import com.ninjasquad.springmockk.MockkBean

@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = [my.package.Main::class]
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class DefaultCalendarControllerIntegrationTest: StringSpec() {
    override fun isolationMode() = IsolationMode.InstancePerTest

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @MockkBean
    lateinit var anotherApiClient: AnotherApiClient
```

but I have trouble trying to mock the response from `anotherApiClient`. Here is the thing: this API client is called when SpringBoot starts up, and the response is cached.

```
@Component
class AnotherApiResponseCache(private val client: AnotherApiClient) {
val cachedResponse = client.get()
```

I've tried multiple places to add my
`every { anotherApiClient.get() } returns "My-Response"`

but every time it's too late: the mocking does not occur soon enough, before `client.get()` is invoked. What am I missing.

SpringBoot 2.7. and com.ninja-squad:springmockk:3.1.1